# MongoDB : Remove first character from string field and update the field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In my documents there is a field of type string `imageUrl: '/xyz/....'` but now I need to remove the first character from the the field and update the the field like `imageUrl: 'xyz/....'` for all documents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On MongoDB version > `4.0` you can execute an [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) in [.update()'s](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline), try below query - which will overwrite `imageUrl` field with new value where `$substr` helps to trim first letter from original string :

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, 
 [{
    $set: {
      imageUrl: {
        $substrBytes: ["$imageUrl", 1, -1]
      }
    }
  }]
 );
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/x5pemlpDXbP)

**Note :** In general query should work fine but in past I've seen couple of issues executing `.updateMany` from clients like `robo3T` or even with older mongo shell, if that's what you see then I would suggest to use `.update()` with option `{multi : true}`.

**Update :** On latest MongoDB versions >= `3.4` you need to use `$substrBytes` which is an alias for `$substr`. Additionally if you wanted to check `/` exists as first character for field `imageUrl` then you need to add `{imageUrl: /^[/]/}` in filter part of `.updateMany()`.

Comment: Can i specify the first character, if available then remove otherwise not.

Comment: @KhairulAlam : Do you mean to say check it `imageUrl` is string or not ? Or check if `/` is in first char or not ?

Comment: Check if / is in first char

Comment: @KhairulAlam : Check my updated answer, I've added query for your filter scenario.. *Note :* regex things won't work in playground, try those in DB..

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
db.collection.update(
         {},
         [{$set:{
            imageUrl:{
                 $substrBytes:[
                               "$imageUrl",
                               1,
                               { $subtract: [ { $strLenBytes: "$imageUrl" }, 1 ] }
                 ]
            }
         }}],
         {multi:true}
)
```

Comment: Can i specify the first character, if available then remove otherwise not.

Comment: sure, in the update [query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#syntax), match the field with a regex